# Nested application shows outer 404 page instead of its own 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an Asp.Net web project and am publishing another one to a subdirectory of the first one. The nested one has its own 404 page which is set with:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Server.GetLastError() is HttpException serverError)
    {
        if (serverError.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Server.Transfer("~/Error Pages/404.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

(The outer 404 page is set the same way to a different 404 page in the outer web project.)

This error page is shown if I'm debugging on my computer (not nested) and select a nonexistent page so I know the error page *can* work. However, when I publish it nested to the other (first) application, if I go to a nonexistent page - I'm shown the outer application's 404 page.

So, How do I make nonexistent pages within the nested application show the nested 404 page?

**EDIT**

[I think I found the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735167/correct-code-for-a-404-page-inside-a-nested-web-application). I'm returning a 404 from the nested 404 page which is probably interpreted to mean that the 404 page itself was not found. So now I'm faced with the problem of how to return a 404 without that happening. See the link.

Comment: Did you configure 2 web.config one for each application (root site and child app)? If so, Are you using `httpErrors` to set up a treatment for 404 requests?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 config files. But I'm using the `Application_Error` in `Global` only. Nothing in the config files.

Comment: Make sure your nested app be an application in IIS instead of virtual directory. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @MarceloVismari Thanks! I now checked on my web host's control panel and it seems that it is indeed not a "web application". Though I can't find any difference between this project and others that I have that _are_ shown as web applications. Where, in the project folder, do I set it as an application?

Comment: it depends on what you intend. There are some differences between Virtual Directory and Application. The last one creates a new AppDomain, has its own global.asax, bin, etc. Virtual Directory is just a pointer to some place on disk. If you just consider this problem probably if you convert to Application and create a new Global.asax into child app, the requests 404 will be treat as you expect.

Comment: @MarceloVismari It turns out the nested one was in fact a web application though it didn't show as one. I edited to show the new information.

Answer (score 2):

As and possible explanation of what is going on:

If your nested application is a `virtual directory` meanwhile root is an `application` i would expect `~` to resolve as root of application.

Thus your inner site resolves root to parent app.

Comment: Thanks! I now checked on my web host's control panel and it seems that it is indeed not a "web application". Though I can't find any difference between this project and others that I have that are shown as web applications. Where, in the project folder, do I set it as an application?

Comment: there is a difference how virtual directory and applications are treated between IIS6 and IIS7 and up. here is a doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: It turns out the nested one was in fact a web application though it didn't show as one. I edited to show the new information.