# Correct code for a 404 page inside a nested web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong), the correct code for an aspx 404 page is:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
Response.StatusDescription = "Page not found";
```

However, I have a web application inside a folder which is under an outer web application, and when I have the aforementioned  code in the nested 404 page, I get the **outer** 404 page. Probably because the nested application is "telling" the outer application that it can't find *the 404 page itself*.

So I removed that code and it shows the correct (=nested) 404 page. But that also means it's returning the wrong response code. Is there a way to achieve both - return a 404 response while staying in the nested application's 404 page instead of being sent up to the out 404 page?

Comment: What about this `Response.StatusCode = 404;`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ [Same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Ok, what about web.config, `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>`?

Comment: The question is not so clear for me :-(

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That's basically the same in this case to `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`. (AFAIK)

Comment: this says you should do both
`TrySkipIisCustomErrors` and `existingResponse="PassThrough"`
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/01/bypassing-iis-error-messages-in-aspnet

Comment: That is too extreme (using `PassThrough`).